# Switch tab bar programmatically in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application and i have a button on my first view which i want to when pressed switch to my second tab programmatically in the tab bar.

I can't quite seem to figure it out how to get the index etc to switch to it i've tried stuff like this.

```
tababarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

With no success.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Thats pretty simple tabBarController is declared as an optional type

```
var tabBarController: UITabBarController? { get }
```

> The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a tab bar
>   controller. If the view controller or one of its ancestors is a child
>   of a tab bar controller, this property contains the owning tab bar
>   controller. This property is nil if the view controller is not
>   embedded inside a tab bar controller.

So you just need to add  "?" at the end of it:

```
@IBAction func goToSecond(_ sender: Any) {
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the tab slides instead of just changing abruptly?

Comment: @vinbhai4u sorry about the long feedback response. I just saw your comment now :(. if you are subclassing UITabBarController you just need to set the selectedIndex `selectedIndex = 1`

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3:

```
func switchToDataTab() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(switchToDataTabCont), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func switchToDataTabCont(){
    tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Swift 4+:

```
func switchToDataTab() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(switchToDataTabCont), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func switchToDataTabCont(){
    tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: This is the simple idea but its really works great, when sometimes click the same  TabViewController screen.. Thank you so much guys..

Answer (score 7):

The solution provided by Leo Dabus (see above) works fine for me. However - some controls have bad states. Can't fix that, but this little workaround will do you all good:

```
func switchToDataTab(){
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2,
        target: self,
        selector: "switchToDataTabCont",
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: false)
}

func switchToDataTabCont(){
    tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: I actually got very similar issue. The `UITableView` state was not changed, even the `tableView.reloadData()` was called. Tx for providing the workaround! Do you probably came into reasoning behind it or a nicer solution?

Comment: Swift 5.0 wants Timer.

Answer (score 2):

Add to Anthony's code:

```
func switchToDataTab(){
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(switchToDataTabCont), userInfo: nil,repeats: false)
}

func switchToDataTabCont(){
    tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Where the selector class has been changed to

```
#selector(switchToDataTabCont)
```