# How to revert back to a previous view from current view in a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am a beginner to XCode and Swift. Currently, I have an app with a UITabBarController that is connected to three UIViewControllers: Home, Add, and Search. How would I implement a "cancel" button in the Add view controller so that it will return to the previous view once tapped?

Comment: Can you give more detail? When you say cancel button what do you want to do, move to home?

Comment: If you want to select a tab bar item programmatically check this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099148/switch-tab-bar-programmatically-in-swift/28099341)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = // 0 home , 1 add , 2 search
```

Answer (score 0):

You can memorize the previously selected tab index before a user switches to another tab by implementing *shouldSelect* defined in **UITabBarControllerDelegate**.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate
{
    var previousSelectedIndex: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        tabBarController.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        previousSelectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        return true
    }

    func cancel() {
        if let index = previousSelectedIndex {
            self.selectedIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```