# Switch tab bar controller view controller after dismissing a modally presented view controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my project you can create a post from a modal view.

When the modal view is dismissed (user presses on save post) I want to switch the tab bar controller to the second tab (post feed screen).

This topic is similar to my problem. The only difference being this is presented from a modal view. I can't figure out how to implement it in my code (tab bar is nil)
[Switch tab bar programmatically in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099148/switch-tab-bar-programmatically-in-swift)

I have added 3 images to make this issue clearer

[image: feature to implement]

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eJlR.png)

[console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbQtz.png)

```
@objc func saveAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print ("> save pressed")
    print(presentingViewController?.tabBarController)
    print(presentingViewController)
    
    presentingViewController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

edit: sorry stack overflow doesn't allow me to add images yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using delegate pattern. But if you prefer not to add a delegate for this, you can do as shown below;

You can switch the tabbar by changing the `selectedIndex` property of `tabBarController`

```
if let presenter = presentingViewController as? LibraryViewController {
        presenter.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
dismiss(animated: true)
```

If you are presenting the modal on navigation controller in tabbar, use:

```
    if let tabBar = presentingViewController as? UITabBarController {
        tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
    }
    dismiss(animated: true)
```

Comment: Hello Jithin ! Thank you for the quick answer. But I have tried this. The problem seems to be that in the modal view the tab bar returns nil. I have edited the post with better detail and my code.

Comment: can you show how you are presenting the modal view controller? Are you using `self.present` or `self.navigationController.present`?

Comment: In Tab[0] of the tab bar controller i have this method a method "self.navigationController?.present(view, animated: true, completion: nil)"

Comment: Ive tried this but it appears that the code within the if statement is not called

Comment: I've updated the answer again since you are presenting on the navigation controller. No need to use the `if let`.

Comment: I think i'll have to find another way of doing this Instagram like navigation... It doesn't seem to be as obvious as it looks haha Ive been on it for 2 weeks (ARGH)

Comment: it didn't work? how many tabs do you have 2 or 3? If its 2, use `presentingViewController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`

Comment: I have 2 tabs. Ive tried putting `selectedIndex =1` too. But when the saveButton is pressed, the view dismisses properly but the tab bar stays on the `selectedIndex = 0`

Comment: can you pls check the value of `presentingViewController' and `presentingViewController?.tabBarController`?

Comment: I put `print(presentingViewController?.tabBarController)` in the code and in the console returned nil. I think its because of the fact that its a modal view and not a view controller that has been pushed onto the navigation controller

Comment: was `presentingViewController` printed as `UITabBarController` ?

Comment: No it presentingViewController was printed as `Optional(<App.MainTabBarController: 0x7f85fc01a600>)`

Comment: I've updated the answer to check for tabbar controller. If this still doesn't work, try casting it to `MainTabBarController` instead of `UITabBarController`